# Problem with Rviz

Tags: rviz, urdf, nxt, ros-diamondback, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to see the simulation of what my Lego NXT is doing with rviz.
Therefore I created the model of my robot with Lego digital designer and the converted it in the right format, that is to say in a .urdf file.
I renamed my sensors and motors with the name that I specified in the .yaml file.
But when I run rviz I get:

```
Robot Model
    Status Error
    ref_0_link No trasform from [ref_0_link] to [/world]
    ...
```

In my nodes I specified a tf between the robot base frame and the world frame, and another between the ultrasonic sensor frame and the robot frame.
In fact the links robot and ultrasonic_sensor are the only ones with `Transform Ok`.
I thought that because of the fact the all the links are children of robot and the joint are fixed there is no need to specify a tf for every link.
Can anyone tell me how to solve my problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41893/problem-with-rviz/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2012-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved my problem publishing a tf for every link of the urdf file.

---

Originally posted by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) with karma: 255 on 2012-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0